# Looking for a laptop with a removable hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

At the moment, I possess a Dell Inspiron 6400. Just removing two screws, I've made the drive removable and can pull it off in one second.

[image]

The new Inspiron and Studio laptops don't support this anymore (the drive is no more on the side but on the back of the laptop). So I’m looking for a new laptop having this kind of feature, or one that can be modded easily.

I also need a :

- Screen >= 15" (if possible resolution > 1366 x 768 resolution)
- Core i5-520M
- Midrange  GPU (like an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650)
- Decent battery life
- minimum fan noise

Comment: Sorry, but shopping type questions are discouraged on SU. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/not-the-shopping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lenovo sells Thinkpads with removable hard drives (at least the x61 has a removable drive). Mine literally comes out after one screw and you can configure the system to posses what you want when you order. Problem is that they're a little expensive.

Comment: Thinkpads have been easily modifiable even before Lenovo had them. My ancient A22m requires removing one screw to remove the hard disk.

Comment: ah. I never had one before i got the one i have now. I have to say i'm very impressed with it. Now if i could just keep it online...

Comment: I've looked at the Hardware Maintenance Manual of the T510 (http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/63y0536.pdf) it seems approaching what I'm looking for. You can buy it with the NVIDIA NVS 3100m, a bit weak for me and I don't much like the display, but it looks like a great laptop. Sadly, the price in Europe (around $2100) of this model is no way near what you can found on the US online store (around $1100).

Comment: what about buying one off newegg or something like that? They have 2 different computers with the NVS100m for much cheaper(assuming that isn't a deal breaker, if it is then lenovo isn't your company)

Comment: Six years later, I can't find a Lenovo laptop with this feature.

Comment: The last one I knew had one that easy was the X220, which is a couple years old, but very functional.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: you can add a hot-removable hard disk to the media bay of Dell laptops (need to check if Studio has these) using a SATA media bay adaptor (cheap on eBay).